# Magento 2 : Rest Api for get customer id with token number

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api

I need **customer id** and **token number** when login customer account in Magento2
I used this API for customer login:

> Method: Post  rest/V1/integration/customer/token

**Body**

`{
"username" : "abc@gmail.com",
"password" : "abc12345!";
}`

Comment: you have to create your own API endpoint that accepts user username as input for search customer data.

Comment: Added an answer below. If you are specifically needing a response containing token and customer id directly from logging in, @fmsthird is correct that you need a custom endpoint. As part of that endpoint you'll have to define a new interface that holds token and customer id and return that. I could probably do a write up of how that could be accomplished if it's what you are looking for :).

Answer (score 2):

The following endpoint (the one you mentioned) will return the access token upon submitting correct user credentials:

> Method: Post rest/V1/integration/customer/token

Then all you need to do is pass that token as a bearer token to this next endpoint and you'll receive all the details for that customer:

> Method: Get rest/V1/customers/me

#### Example Request

curl --request GET \
  --url https://example.com/rest/V1/customers/me \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer x6qa7biotlej2s2li1tl3zzx5ww42lt8'

#### Example Response

Customer id is `id` in the response

```
{
    "id": 77819,
    "group_id": 1,
    "default_shipping": "11169",
    "created_at": "2018-08-23 15:49:17",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-11 22:33:59",
    "created_in": "US",
    "email": "testperson@somedomain.com",
    "firstname": "Test",
    "lastname": "Person",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "id": 11170,
            "customer_id": 77819,
            "region": {
                "region_code": "Etelä-Savo",
                "region": "Etelä-Savo",
                "region_id": 976
            },
            "region_id": 976,
            "country_id": "FI",
            "street": [
                "Finlandiantie"
            ],
            "telephone": "1234",
            "postcode": "58450",
            "city": "Punkaharju",
            "firstname": "Test",
            "lastname": "Person",
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "some_custom_attribute",
                    "value": "A custom value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "is_subscribed": false
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "some_custom_attribute",
            "value": "A custom value"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Full working example

YourModule/Customer/etc/di.xml

```
    <preference for="YourModule\Customer\Api\AuthServiceInterface"
                type="YourModule\Customer\Model\AuthService" />
```

YourModule/Customer/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V2/login" method="POST">
    <service class="YourModule\Customer\Api\AuthServiceInterface" method="login"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

YourModule/Customer/Api/Data/LoginResponseInterface.php

```
interface LoginResponseInterface {
    /**#@+
     * Constants defined for keys of the data array. Identical to the name of the getter in snake case
     */
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token';
    const CUSTOMER_ID = 'customer_id';
    /**#@-*/

    /**
     * Get access token
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccessToken();

    /**
     * Set access token
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAccessToken($token);

    /**
     * Set customerId
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStoreWebsiteId($id);

    /**
     * Get customerId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCustomerId();
}
```

YourModule/Customer/Model/Data/LoginResponse.php

```
class LoginResponse extends AbstractModel implements LoginResponseInterface {

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAccessToken(){
        return $this->getData(self::ACCESS_TOKEN);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function setAccessToken($token){
        return $this->setData(self::ACCESS_TOKEN, $token);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function setCustomerId($id){
        return $this->setData(self::CUSTOMER_ID, $id);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getCustomerId(){
        return $this->getData(self::CUSTOMER_ID);
    }
}
```

YourModule/Customer/Api/AuthServiceInterface.php

```
interface AuthServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * Login and return accessToken, customer info
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @return Data\LoginResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function login($username, $password);
}
```

YourModule/Customer/Model/AuthService.php

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use YourModule\Customer\Api\AuthServiceInterface;
use Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory as TokenModelFactory;
use Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Oauth\Token\CollectionFactory as TokenCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\Token\RequestThrottler;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class AuthService implements AuthServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * Token Model
     *
     * @var TokenModelFactory
     */
    private $tokenModelFactory;

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    private $eventManager;

    /**
     * Customer Account Service
     *
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    private $accountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator
     */
    private $validatorHelper;

    /**
     * Token Collection Factory
     *
     * @var TokenCollectionFactory
     */
    private $tokenModelCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var Data\LoginResponseFactory
     */
    protected $_loginResponseFactory;

    /**
     * @var RequestThrottler
     */
    private $requestThrottler;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * Initialize service
     *
     * @param TokenModelFactory $tokenModelFactory
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     * @param TokenCollectionFactory $tokenModelCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator $validatorHelper
     * @param Data\LoginResponseFactory $loginResponseFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        TokenModelFactory $tokenModelFactory,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        TokenCollectionFactory $tokenModelCollectionFactory,
        CredentialsValidator $validatorHelper,
        \YourModule\Customer\Model\Data\LoginResponseFactory $loginResponseFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager = null
    ) {
        $this->tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->tokenModelCollectionFactory = $tokenModelCollectionFactory;
        $this->validatorHelper = $validatorHelper;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(ManagerInterface::class);

        $this->_loginResponseFactory = $loginResponseFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->validatorHelper->validate($username, $password);
        $this->getRequestThrottler()->throttle($username, RequestThrottler::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER);
        try {
            $customerDataObject = $this->accountManagement->authenticate($username, $password);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->getRequestThrottler()->logAuthenticationFailure($username, RequestThrottler::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER);
            throw new AuthenticationException(
                __(
                    'The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. '
                    . 'Please wait and try again later.'
                )
            );
        }
        $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_login', ['customer' => $customerDataObject]);
        $this->getRequestThrottler()->resetAuthenticationFailuresCount($username, RequestThrottler::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER);
        $token = $this->tokenModelFactory->create()->createCustomerToken($customerDataObject->getId())->getToken();

        $loginResponse = $this->_loginResponseFactory->create();
        $loginResponse->setCustomerId($customerDataObject->getId());
        $loginResponse->setAccessToken($token);
        
        return $loginResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Get request throttler instance
     *
     * @return RequestThrottler
     * @deprecated 100.0.4
     */
    private function getRequestThrottler()
    {
        if (!$this->requestThrottler instanceof RequestThrottler) {
            return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(RequestThrottler::class);
        }
        return $this->requestThrottler;
    }
}
```